# Multiple JOIN and SELECT Statements from eight tables

Tags: mysql, sql, labview

I am trying to make an SQL statement that takes eight different numbers and searches eight different tables from one database for the corresponding value. I keep getting invalid syntax, but I can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
SELECT cable_length.ID, drawing.ID, optional.ID, output_type.ID, pressure_range.ID, pressure_type.ID, series.ID, termination.ID 
FROM
(
    SELECT value AS cable_length FROM A1 WHERE A1.id = %s
    JOIN SELECT value AS drawing FROM A2 WHERE A2.id = %s,
    JOIN SELECT value AS optional FROM A3 WHERE A3.id = %s,
    JOIN SELECT value AS output_type FROM A4 WHERE A4.id = %s,
    JOIN SELECT value AS pressure_range FROM A5 WHERE A5.id = %s,
    JOIN SELECT value AS pressure_type FROM A6 WHERE A6.id = %s,
    JOIN SELECT value AS series FROM A7 WHERE A7.id = %s, 
    JOIN SELECT value AS termination FROM A8 WHERE A8.id = %s
);
```

The %s will be changed to numbers only. The column name in each table is "ID" and "Value". I want to search by "ID" and return "Value". The table names are cable_length, etc. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you flow is not correct. where condition always comes at last. also enclose your join statments in () and join them on the first table with on clause

Comment: You are listing a lot of columns in your `SELECT` clause that don't appear to exist.

Comment: Put those joined selects into parentheses plus give them a name: `JOIN (SELECT ... WHERE A.id = ...) AS joined_table_3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that all 8 values are present, you can join like this:

```
SELECT  A1.value as cable_length
  , A2.value as drawing
  , A3.value as optional
  , A4.value as output_type
  , A5.value as pressure_range
  , A6.value as pressure_type
  , A7.value as series
  , A7.value as termination
FROM A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8
WHERE A1.ID = %s
  AND A2.ID = %s
  AND A3.ID = %s
  AND A4.ID = %s
  AND A5.ID = %s
  AND A6.ID = %s
  AND A7.ID = %s
  AND A8.ID = %s
```

If you do not know this, but you're guaranteed that the first value is present, then your query has to get uglier because you need left joins.

```
SELECT  A1.value as cable_length
  , A2.value as drawing
  , A3.value as optional
  , A4.value as output_type
  , A5.value as pressure_range
  , A6.value as pressure_type
  , A7.value as series
  , A7.value as termination
FROM A1
  LEFT JOIN A2
    ON A2.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A3
    ON A3.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A4
    ON A4.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A5
    ON A5.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A6
    ON A6.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A7
    ON A7.ID = %s
  LEFT JOIN A8
    ON A8.ID = %s
WHERE A1.ID = %s
```

If none of the values are guaranteed present, the hack is to have a subquery that is a `UNION ALL` of 8 queries that return the 8 columns with only one filled, then select the `MAX` of each column as that column name.

This is an awful trick that I've used in the past to avoid performance problems with many left joins that only occasionally join.

Incidentally 8 tables named A1..A8 suggests that you need someone who is experienced with databases to look over your design and give you a much better layout.

Comment: When I run this, it returns: Table 'labview_test.A1' doesn't exist

Comment: Use your actual table names instead of A1, A2, etc.  I was going off of what your problem description said.

Comment: The tables aren't named A1..A8. The tables are cable_length, etc in the same database. The values in each of the tables are "ID" and "Value".

Comment: btilly, when I changed the A1, A2 etc to the table names I get: labview_test.optional_value' doesn't exist

Comment: @user1486004 Then write optional.value or even labview_test.optional.value instead of labview_test.optional_value.  The form of the SQL I gave is correct.  Your schema I can't help you with because I don't have it to refer to.

Comment: Got it! the second SQL you gave worked. You're the man! thank you so much! thanks everyone else too!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want. Maybe not, I just rewrote your query:

```
SELECT
  cable_length.ID,
  drawing.ID,
  optional.ID,
  output_type.ID,
  pressure_range.ID,
  pressure_type.ID,
  series.ID,
  termination.ID 
FROM (SELECT ID FROM A1 WHERE A1.id = %s) AS cable_length
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A2 WHERE A2.id = %s) AS drawing
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A3 WHERE A3.id = %s) AS optional
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A4 WHERE A4.id = %s) AS output_type
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A5 WHERE A5.id = %s) AS pressure_range
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A6 WHERE A6.id = %s) AS pressure_type
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A7 WHERE A7.id = %s) AS series
JOIN (SELECT ID FROM A8 WHERE A8.id = %s) AS termination;
```

Comment: You have no `ON` syntax, how are the tables joining?

Comment: I don't see a join in the original query, maybe all he wants to know is all possible combinations :)

Comment: When I try to run it, I get: Table 'labview_test.A1' doesn't exist

Comment: What are your eight tables? In your original query you used A1, A2, .. A8.

Comment: My eight tables are cable_length, drawing, optional, output_type, pressure_range, pressure_type, series, termination

Comment: @bluefeet you only need ON if you have conditions.  Also you do not need ON clauses in the same order as the joins.  (With left joins the ordering of the ONs actually changes the meaning of the query!)

Answer (score 0):

UNION ALL will work in this case, but it may not be the best solution, not to mention the mess (see the answer provided by @btilly).  Also note that this is SQL Server syntax, which may differ slightly to MySql

```
select max(cable_length), max(drawing), max(optional), max(output_type), max(pressure_range), max(pressure_type), max(series), max(termination)

from
(
    SELECT value as cable_length, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null 
    FROM cable_length WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, value as drawing, null, null, null, null, null, null, null 
    FROM drawing WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, value as optional, null, null, null, null, null, null 
    FROM optional WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, null, value as output_type, null, null, null, null, null 
    FROM output_type WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, null, null, value as pressure_range, null, null, null 
    FROM pressure_range WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, null, null, null, value as pressure_type, null, null 
    FROM pressure_type WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, null, null, null, null, value as series, null 
    FROM series WHERE id = %s

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null, null, null, null, null, null, null, value as termination 
    FROM termination WHERE id = %s
);
```

Comment: You can't `SELECT *` with this approach, you need to `SELECT max(cable_length) as cable_length, max(drawing) as drawing, ...` to collapse it back to one row.

Comment: @btilly - not if the ID is the primary key, otherwise, yes, you might be right.  Don't really know at this point because we don't know the table structures.

Comment: If the ID is the primary key, you're going to wind up with 8 rows, each with 7 nulls, rather than 1 row with all 8 values.  That is the whole point of the `max` hack.

Comment: @btilly - gotcha, in the final output.  Thanks.